# drawString not drawing text on my game

Tags: monogame, drawstring, spritebatch

I am new in this monogame stuff. Watched few tutorials and figured it out how to do some stuff. But here is a problem, when it comes to drawing string on game surface, it does not work.

I downloaded a MonoGame sample from one page (https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=24923400704D0887!3539&authkey=!AAwQxeoQwb_cmhk&ithint=file%2c.zip) and it suited my needs for my game. Game works well all the textures and graphics and everything, but when it comes to printing it does nothing.

I have `SpriteFont sf` declared right after my class, have it initialized

```
sf = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("myFont");
```

And in draw method right between `spriteBatch.Begin` and `spriteBatch.End`

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(sf, "Score", new Vector(100, 100), Color.Red);
```

but still doesn't work.

Font loads great, I tested it in other new Monogame project for WP and it even draws!

So I blame this template-sample I downloaded. Don't know this stuff a lot so I hope someone can help me and explain in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by removing any other draw calls. If you can then see the string, it means that the string is being rendered behind something else. Then you need to play with layerDepth values (from 0.0 to 1.0 where 1.0 is the front)